# Wait trigger is finish to start another one with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have something like :

```
$('#test').bind('go', function(event, top, left,w,h) {
  $('#test').animate({left: left, top : top, width: w,height: h},1000,function() {
     $('#test').animate({left: 0, top :0, width: w,height: h},1000)  ;      
  })
});

$('#test').trigger('go', [150, 200,100,80]);
$('#test').trigger('go', [250, 200,100,80]);
$('#test').trigger('go', [350, 200,100,80]);
```

but the 2nd et 3rd trigger start before the end of the first one. i want the next main.trigger start when the previous is complete.

Try it : http://jsfiddle.net/9NLrR/6/

thanks

Comment: what is `bidule` and `main` can you please make a fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net) to understand more

Comment: What you need is queus, like this: 

http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/06/22/how-to-use-custom-jquery-animation-queues/

I'm not very familiar with them, but I think with a little reading, you can find out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test this:

```
<div style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red; position:absolute;" id="test"></div>​
```

and script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#test').bind('go', function(event, top, left,w,h) {
        $('#test').animate({left: left, top : top, width: w,height: h},1000);  
        $('#test').animate({left: 0, top : 0, width: w,height: h},1000);     
    });

    $('#test').trigger('go', [150, 200,100,80]);
    $('#test').trigger('go', [250, 200,100,80]);
    $('#test').trigger('go', [350, 200,100,80]);
</script>
```

Comment: No, by default jQuery do not wait the end of action to start another

Comment: the three action are in order but quasi simultaneous

Comment: sorry your code works but i don't understant why my code do not work

Comment: the only thing that is changes are the element selectors. look at that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can play using maintaining a variable value

```
var trigger=0;

main.bind('go', function(event, top, left,w,h,triggervalue) {

   if(triggervalue==trigger)
   { 
    bidule.animate({left: left, top : top, width: w,height: h},1000);
    trigger++;
   }

}

main.trigger('go', [150, 200,100,80,1]);
main.trigger('go', [250, 200,100,80,2]);
main.trigger('go', [350, 200,100,80,3]);
```

Comment: I just thought that by checking a varibale value while calling animate can make some difference .If it is not working then i will try to find a different solution and will put it here but i have applied such variable value concept in some of my jquery code and they have worked fine